# Marigold leaves drying up

Tags: diagnosis, flowers, container-gardening, flowering, marigold

I have potted two marigolds in one seven inch pot. Both plants are having their leaved dried up. I Water them daily.

Weather in my area min: 10 °C/65 °F, max: 25 °C/77 °F. Can someone please help me with the reason as well as a solution?

| Flowers |  |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Comment: With those temperatures, I would say you're overwatering.

Comment: Which type of marigold - Calendula or Tagetes? A photo would be helpful otherwise. And is 10degC daytime temperature?